# Javascript search filter on user generated table from Django

Tags: javascript, html, django

I'm trying to create a dynamic search engine with javascript from a user generated table that is created with a form that adds a song to the table. I want to search the list that's already created. It's not doing anything when I type in anything and no errors in the DOM. Can some someone tell me where i went wrong?

Here's my HTML:

```
 {% extends "base.html" %}
    {% load static %}
    {% block title %}My Song List{% endblock %}
    {% block content %}
 <input type="text" name="search"  placeholder="Search by Title" class="animated-search-form" id="myInput onkeyup="search();"> 

 <div class="translucent-form-overlay">
 <form action="/" method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ form }}
   <input type="submit" value="Add Song" />
 </form>
 </div>

 <div id="list-container">
 <h1 style="text-decoration:underline">Sorted Alphabetically by Song Title</h1>
 <h5>
         <table id="myList">
     {% for song in song_list %} //song_list is the model
     <tr> <td>Title: {{song.title}}</td> <td>Artist: {{song.artist}}</td> <td>Year: {{song.year}}</td> <td>Genre: {{song.genre}}</td></tr>
     {% endfor %}
         </table>
 </h5>
 </div>

 {% endblock %}
```

And here's my javascript:

```
 function myFunction() {
   // Declare variables 
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
     input = document.getElementById("myInput");
     filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
     table = document.getElementById("myList");
     tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

     // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
     for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
       td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
       if (td) {
         if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
           tr[i].style.display = "";
         } else {
             tr[i].style.display = "none";
           }
       } 
     }
 }
```

I tried first with JQuery with same results, then found a simpler solution in w3c schools using pure javascript. However, that version created the table data in the HTML. My data is actually stored in database, rendered in Django and passed back to the HTML.

Thanks for any advice or input,
Mike

Comment: end quote `"` is missing in `id` attribute of  your input tag. and you are calling `search` function on keyup which should be `myFunction` as per your declaration

Comment: Or I'm sorry I said I tried JQuery, that was actually confusing so I tried Vue.js initially. Then went to pure javascript

Comment: oh shoot, ok I missed that. Thanks

Comment: ah ok got it, all that time for stupid syntax errors and not renaming the function in javascript. Thank you for the prompt response. I need to be more careful.